# Change a variable value after OnInitializedAsync()

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have this component that calls multiple APIs. I want to show the page only when all the calls finishes, so I added a bool and I initialized it with false that changes to true when the `OnInitializedAsync()` finishes, but the value does not change and the page keep showing the loader. What am I doing wrong?

Component:

```
@if (ComponenetReady) {
  // Show Stuff 
} Else {
  // Show loader
}

 @Code
{
public bool ComponenetReady { get; set; } = false; 

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
            // Await APIs calls 
            ComponenetReady = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try calling StateHasChanged() after setting the flag.  You might also need to move your flag from OnInitializedAsync to OnAfterRenderAsync().

Comment: This should have worked already. So there is another problem. Replace the API Calls with Task.Delay() and create a [mre]

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code above.  The component re-renders after `OnInitializedAsync` completes, so `ComponenetReady ` will be true.  The problem is in the code you haven't shown us.  Put a break point on `ComponenetReady = true;` and see when it gets hit.

Answer (score -1):

Since it is an async task it will be running on a different thread. Try `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);` right after your `ComponenetReady = true;`

Comment: Blazor on WebAssembly has no 'different threads'.